# Pyqt Show Widget in two monitors at the same time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm doing an aplication to show results of a race.

When a rider arrives, a decoder take arrival time, I read this information by Serial Port or TC/IP Port. I decode this information and show rider time and the averall classification of all riders.

The riders arrives every 30 seconds or less.

I want to show this results in a external TV or Monitor. I can't see this monitor, that is why I want to see the widget that shows the results simultaneously on my monitor and the external monitor.

The results are showed in a `QTableView` inside a `QMainWindow`.

I have simplified the program code to be able to publish the question:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout,QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton,QLabel,QMainWindow,QStatusBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow
import sys


class ShowResults(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(600,600)
        display_monitor = 1
        monitor = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(display_monitor)
        self.move(monitor.left(), monitor.top())
        self.showFullScreen() 
                
        self.create_GUI()
             
    def create_GUI(self):
           
        central_widget=QWidget()
        layout=QGridLayout(central_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        pb_show_times=QPushButton('START')

        layout.addWidget(pb_show_times,1,1)
             

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
print('Number of Monitors ',len(app.screens()))
ShowResults()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you need? Because in your question you specifically use the verb "show", but in your code there are interactive elements (a button). So, should the widgets *both* also allow interaction? Or is it only about mirroring? Also, how is the information going to be updated?

Comment: @musicamante thank you for your interest. I will edit my question and explain it more.

Comment: @RBenet This doesn't seem to be about programming at all. If you want to know how to mirror an application on another monitor, I suggest you consult the documentation for your operating system.